# Proguard and Scoreloop

Tags: android, proguard, scoreloop

I'm trying to use Proguard on my Android projet and keep getting the same error at runtime on the Scoreloop (version 3.0.3) library...

I defined the proguard config file as follow in the project.properties file:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
proguard.enabled=true
```

And here is my proguard-project.txt file (with everything included in case I did something wrong somewhere...):

```
# ####### #
# Project #
# ####### #
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference


# ##### #
# AdMob #
# ##### #
-keep public class com.google.ads.** {*;}
-keep public class com.google.gson.** {*;}


# #### #
# ACRA #
# #### #
# we need line numbers in our stack traces otherwise they are pretty useless
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# ACRA needs "annotations" so add this... 
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {*;}

# keep this around for some enums and classes that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {*;}
#-keep class org.acra.ReportField {*;}
-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {*;}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter {
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter {
    public org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportsSenderWorker handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}


# ######### #
# Scoreloop #
# ######### #
-dontwarn com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.**
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.fortumo.FortumoPaymentProviderController {*;}
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.fortumo.FortumoPaymentProvider {*;}
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.paypalx.PayPalXPaymentProviderController {*;}
-dontwarn com.scoreloop.client.android.core.ui.WebViewDialog
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.ui.WebViewDialog {*;}
-keep class com.facebook.android.** {*;}


# ############## #
# In-App Billing #
# ############## #
# -keep class com.android.vending.billing.**


# ####### #
# OrmLite #
# ####### #
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

I'm getting this error at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.b.aw]
    at com.scoreloop.client.android.core.b.j.a(SourceFile:692)
    at com.scoreloop.client.android.core.b.j.<init>(SourceFile:368)
    at com.sofresh.games.megaflux.MegaFluxApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:106)
    at com.sofresh.games.megaflux.MegaFluxApplication_.onCreate(SourceFile:19)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
    ... 10 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.b.aw]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
    at com.scoreloop.client.android.core.b.j.a(SourceFile:684)
```

From the file mapping.txt, I found this regarding the problematic classes and calls:

```
com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Client -> com.scoreloop.client.android.core.b.j:
    java.util.Map a -> a
    com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.ClientObserver b -> b
    com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Session c -> c
    103:104:boolean a(java.util.Properties,java.lang.String,boolean) -> a
    155:178:java.util.Properties a(android.content.Context) -> a
    182:185:void a(java.util.Properties,java.lang.String) -> a
    188:194:void a(java.util.Properties,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> a
    198:232:void a(android.content.Context,java.lang.String) -> a
    380:387:void a(java.util.Properties) -> a
    638:640:int b(java.util.Properties,java.lang.String) -> b
    684:692:void a(java.lang.Class) -> a
    708:711:void a$2a1b557e(com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Session) -> a
    715:718:boolean a(com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Session) -> b
    722:723:void b(android.content.Context) -> b
[...]
com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Session -> com.scoreloop.client.android.core.b.aw:
[...]
```

So I thought the error said that it couldn't find the constructor of Client taking a Session. I tried adding the following to my proguard conf:

```
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.**
```

With no luck, now I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Session]
    at com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Client.a(SourceFile:692)
    at com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Client.a(SourceFile:605)
    at com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Client.<init>(SourceFile:368)
    at com.blabla.MyApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:106)
    at com.blabla.MyApplication_.onCreate(SourceFile:19)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
    ... 10 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Session]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
    at com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Client.a(SourceFile:684)
```

And now I'm a bit lost on what to try next... Any idea and enlightenment on this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a response from Scoreloop support and some tests on my side, here is the ProGuard configuration for Scoreloop:

```
# ######### #
# Scoreloop #
# ######### #
-dontwarn com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.**
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.fortumo.FortumoPaymentProviderController {*;}
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.fortumo.FortumoPaymentProvider {*;}
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.paypalx.PayPalXPaymentProviderController {*;}
-dontwarn com.scoreloop.client.android.core.ui.WebViewDialog
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.ui.WebViewDialog {*;}
-keep class com.facebook.android.** {*;}
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.** { *; }
```

Comment: Still get NoClassDefError on com.zong.android.engine.provider.ZongPersistanceProvider

Answer (score 2):

The code performs reflection and can't find a constructor, so you indeed have to make sure that it's preserved. Your -keep option is preserving all classes/fields/methods in the specified package and its subpackages:

```
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.** {*;}
```

However, the code is probably trying to find the constructor of a class outside this package -- the stack trace unfortunately doesn't tell. You'll have to figure out which class (or set of classes) this is, and then keep its constructor.

Note that your -keepclassmembers option doesn't do anything (because it doesn't specify any class members), but it is not necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Without the source it was difficult to really tell what to change... Fortunately the Scoreloop support answered and I manage to find the solution !